# Search for vector of motifs in vector of sequences with dataframe output

Tags: r, dataframe, bioinformatics

I have a set of nucleotide sequences in a vector of strings called x.

I want to check whether some (say 10) motifs are present in x.  I want to produce a data frame or table where the rows are the sequences in X and the columns are the patterns/motifs are in the vector sdseqs.

```
sdframe <- data.frame
sdseqs = c("AGGAG.+ATG", 
"AGAAG.+ATG","AAAGG.+ATG","GGAGG.+ATG","GAAGA.+ATG",
"GGAGA.+ATG","AAGGT.+ATG","AGGAA.+ATG","AAGGA.+ATG","GTGGA.+ATG")
for (i in 1:10) {
sdframe <- cbind(sdframe,(grepl(sdseqs[i], x)))
}
```

This code works just fine but the first column of the data frame will be empty, with question marks.  The other columns are populated with true and false - that's what i want.

I tried to define an empty data frame outside the loop at the beginning.  I am new to R and I am coming from Perl.  This what I usually did in Perl: you define variables to be used within a loop outside. How can I do this in R?

Also, a viable option would be to delete the first column from my data frame, but that does not seem so straightforward to me.

Any help is appreciated.

The output i Get with my code now:

```
  sdframe                                                            
[1,] ?       TRUE  FALSE TRUE  TRUE  FALSE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  FALSE
[2,] ?       FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE  TRUE 
[3,] ?       FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE TRUE  FALSE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE 
[4,] ?       TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[5,] ?       FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[6,] ?       FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE TRUE 
[7,] ?       FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE
[8,] ?       FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE
[9,] ?       FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[10,] ?       FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[11,] ?       FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

I want the same but without the first column of ?. Note my x has 11 sequences, the motifs i checked for are the column (10 columns, 11 counting the first with ?)

Comment: you typically don't need to define a structure in advance in R.  can you provide the x sequence?  or an accession code?

Comment: I can't provide the exact sequences in x at the moment but that should not make a difference. They are sequences from one paper which I incorporated into a vector x using Biostrings function readDNAStringSet. so x is basically a vector with dna sequences. 

If i don't define the data frame before it gives me error because in the loop I use cbind to add each column to an existing dataframe.

Comment: updated my solution based on your output sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common R solution would use a function from the apply family to apply a function over a a vector.

```
sdseqs = c(
  "AGGAG.+ATG",
  "AGAAG.+ATG",
  "AAAGG.+ATG",
  "GGAGG.+ATG",
  "GAAGA.+ATG",
  "GGAGA.+ATG",
  "AAGGT.+ATG",
  "AGGAA.+ATG",
  "AAGGA.+ATG",
  "GTGGA.+ATG"
)

sdframe <- sapply(sdseqs, function(one.motif) {
  grepl(one.motif, x = x)
})

sdframe

     AGGAG.+ATG AGAAG.+ATG AAAGG.+ATG GGAGG.+ATG GAAGA.+ATG GGAGA.+ATG AAGGT.+ATG AGGAA.+ATG AAGGA.+ATG GTGGA.+ATG
[1,]      FALSE       TRUE      FALSE      FALSE       TRUE       TRUE       TRUE      FALSE       TRUE      FALSE
[2,]      FALSE       TRUE      FALSE      FALSE       TRUE       TRUE       TRUE      FALSE       TRUE      FALSE
[3,]      FALSE       TRUE      FALSE      FALSE       TRUE       TRUE       TRUE      FALSE       TRUE      FALSE

sdframe.t <- t(sdframe)

sdframe.t

            [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
AGGAG.+ATG FALSE FALSE FALSE
AGAAG.+ATG  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
AAAGG.+ATG FALSE FALSE FALSE
GGAGG.+ATG FALSE FALSE FALSE
GAAGA.+ATG  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
GGAGA.+ATG  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
AAGGT.+ATG  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
AGGAA.+ATG FALSE FALSE FALSE
AAGGA.+ATG  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
GTGGA.+ATG FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly. When i run this code however my output has got the motifs in the columns (the one you posted are in the rows) and my rows are the sequences in my x. I get what I want but was just wondering why your output is the other way around? Also i do not use the line sdframe <- t(res) cos it doesn t work. I do not have any res and it does not find. In cae it wasn't clear, I am a very beginner !

Comment: I want exactly what I got in mine but was wondering how it is possible that yours is the otherway around if I use the same code.

Comment: Our frames are in opposite orientations because you didn't use the transpose function!  What happened when you tried to use t(res) ?

Comment: Hah!  You are a good debugger.  I said t(res) when I should have said t(sdframe).  I fixed it.

Comment: Thanks Mark this was very helpful.

Comment: My pleasure.  Since you're new to SO:  don't forget to accept and or up-vote helpful answers.

Answer (score 0):

In first line in fact you do not create a `data.frame`. So your output is a `list`.

Instead of `cbind` you need `rbind` to add rows:

```
sdframe <- data.frame()
sdseqs = c("AGGAG.+ATG", 
       "AGAAG.+ATG","AAAGG.+ATG","GGAGG.+ATG","GAAGA.+ATG",
       "GGAGA.+ATG","AAGGT.+ATG","AGGAA.+ATG","AAGGA.+ATG","GTGGA.+ATG")
for (i in 1:10) {
sdframe <- rbind(sdframe,(grepl(sdseqs[i], x)))
}
```

Comment: why would you use a for loop?

Comment: if I use this method it the sequences in x becomes the columns and my 10 patterns in sdseqs become the rows. I want the other way around.

Comment: OP is new to R.

Comment: @GabrieleGab Fine. But in your code `sdframe` becomes a `list` after the `loop`. You can verify with `typeof(sdframe)`. Do you need a `list` or a `dataframe`?

Comment: I just edited the main post; I added the output for my code and I wrote below what I neeed. exactly same output but without first column. Have a look at it it will be more clear. Thanks again for taking the time

Comment: @GabrieleGab You can get rid of first column with `sdframe[,-1]`. But this is not proper way. What you define in the beginning and what you get are different.

Comment: Yes I checked and my sdframe is in fact a list. I understand, it looks kind of clumsy. How would you obtain this same kind of output in a cleaner, more elegant way?

Comment: @GabrieleGab I would use above code in the answer which makes a dataframe and add rows. Then in the end I would use `t(sdframe)` which will swap rows to columns.

Comment: Thanks that was very helpful